# Get the body of all unseen messages from an address IMAP Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap

I would like to get the body of all unseen messages from an address using the IMAP library in Python 3. I was able to get all the message's body using this code here

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

mail.login( 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD' )

mail.list

mail.select("inbox")


obj, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

for num in data [0].split():

    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, 'BODY[1]')

print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))

mail.close()
```

Is there any way that I could narrow the search to just return unseen messages from a single address like email@address.com? This site [here](https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/#mailbox-status) shows the unseen flag and this user was able to get a list of email addresses that I have received emails from using this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052157/is-there-a-way-using-python-3-imaplib-to-retrieve-both-the-sender-address-the). I was unable to figure out how to change the code to work because it was missing parts. Is there some way to combine these three to achieve the results I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ALL` with `UNSEEN`. IMAP has [many search keys](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) you can use, `ALL` is not the only one.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been able to catch that. Any way to filter per user? So then I just get unseen messages from one user not all?

Comment: Of course. You might have noticed the `FROM` key in that list? `search(None, 'UNSEEN FROM "arnt"')` will match unseen mail from me (and a few thousand other false positives, I'm not quite the only arnt).

Comment: Thanks that should do it.